# I am trying to return an array of User objects but my variable $database->FetchArray() return false

Tags: php, fetch, oci8

My program does not execute the foreach because $database->FetchArray() is false.

However my request is correct and executed ($success is equal to true).

```php
public static function FindBasicRecipients(): array|bool
    {
        $database = new Database('log', 'pwd', 'desc');
        $database->Connect();
        $database->Parse("SELECT 
            ID_WORKSPACE_USERS,
            LOGIN_WORKSPACE_USERS
            FROM WORKSPACE_USERS
            WHERE FONCTION_WORKSPACE_USERS IN ('Job 1','Job 2', 'Job 3')
            ORDER BY EMAIL_WORKSPACE_USERS"
        );
        $success = $database->Execute();
        if ($success) {
            $basicRecipients = [];
            foreach ($database->FetchArray() as $row) {
                $basicRecipients[] = new User(
                    $row['ID_WORKSPACE_USERS'],
                    $row['LOGIN_WORKSPACE_USERS']
                );
            }
            $database->FreeStatement();
            $database->Close();
            return $basicRecipients;
        } else {
            $database->FreeStatement();
            $database->Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is my Database class with my FetchArray method :

```php
public function FetchArray($mode = null): array|false
    {
        return oci_fetch_array($this->statement, $mode);
    }
```

Comment: Salut ! Traduis le français en anglais et mets le contenu de ta classe Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`oci_fetch_array()` just returns one row of results. If it returns anything, You'll loop over the columns of the first row, not all the results. It will return `false` if there are no results or you've already fetched all the results.

To loop over all the results, you should use

```
while ($row = $database->FetchArray())
```

Comment: Thanks you, it's good for me. Except when I filter with WHERE and a string containing accents

Comment: That sounds like an encoding problem.